# Programación crawler

Tags: python

tengo que programar un crawler en Python de la siguiente manera:

CoinMarketCap (https://coinmarketcap.com/) es una web con contenido acerca de las 100 criptomonedas
con más capitalización de mercado. Tengo que programar un crawler que extraiga los nombres y la capitalización de todas les monedas que se muestran en CoinMarketCap. Para ello, sólo hay que modificar dos líneas de código:

- la URL de inicio.
- la expresión XPath que selecciona el contenido a capturar.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class toni_spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "toni_spider"

    # Indicamos la URL que queremos analizar.
    # Aquí hay que incluir la URL de inicio:

    start_urls = [
          ""
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
          # Extraemos el nombre de la moneda.
          # Aquí hay que incluir la expresión 'xpath' que nos         retorna los nombres de las monedas.

          for currency in response.xpath(''):

                yield {
                      'currency': currency.extract()
                }
if __name__ == "__main__":

     # Creamos un crawler.
     process = CrawlerProcess({
             'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
             'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {'s3': None},
             'LOG_ENABLED': False
})

# Inicializamos el crawler con nuestra araña.
process.crawl(toni_spider)

# Lanzamos la araña.
process.start()
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo completar el código (incluir la URL a analizar e incluir el xpath que retorna el nombre y la capitalización de las monedas)?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.